# Tizen: Permit all applications install not working

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

Did anyone have this problem?
I followed the process to get the certificates author.crt and device-profile.xml.
It correctly has created the profile in security profiles section, associating the respective .p12 files.
Then when I right-click the device and choose "Permit all applications installation" it says certificate isn't registered! Is it a IDE bug?

Comment: Are you sure, that your project uses new security profile?

Comment: I suggest you delete the security profiles and then import your .crt and device profile again. If possible, clean your workspace.

Comment: Thank you. The cleansing worked. I even remade the certificates and now its ok. It´s strange, but I already tried this before...whatever.

Comment: if you found solution for your problem, please add the answer and accept it, so other may find it easier in the future ;)

Comment: If you did a rename of devices.profile.xml your error can appear. undo your renaming !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suggest you delete the security profiles and then import your .crt and device profile again. If possible, clean your workspace. –  Vykthur D

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add the device in the distributor certificate. The cause of this error is that the device is not yet added to the distributor certificate. The link below will guide you on how you can add device to the distributor certificate.

https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen3531/index.html
(under Distributor certificate section).